# What are the specific constraints of recruiting in rapidly growing startups?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, startup

**Background:**

The first time I had to grad exams as university lecturer, I realized how wrong were all exams/homework I wrote as a student — because I didn't understand grader's expectations/requirements. I truly believed that **if I had**, as a student, **the opportunity to experience what mattered** — and what not — for the grader (i.e., to get into his/her head), **I would have done better** by tailoring my answers to his/her needs.

**Problem:**

Fast-forward: I am now **applying for a job** (namely full stack developer — but it doesn't matter as you'll see) **in a rapidly growing startup**. This startup is 3 years old, located in western Europe, works in a currently trending sector, has a about 20–30 employees (I guess), and recently raised a few million growth equity in Series A. The startup is hiring about 5 people into similar positions (some focusing rather on the front-end, the back-end, or data-analytics — but all fairly versatile), plus others for support functions. I may be quite under-skilled/experienced for the position(s) I am applying to.

I want to **better understand their needs in recruitment** — and especially focusing on their rapid growth "issue" (need to quickly hire a few people).

**Question:**

Beyond what an employer looks for every time in a candidate (matches the position and the company, is reliable, won't cause problem and will add value to the company, etc.), and beyond the specifics of the position (technical skills),

> **what are the specific requirements and constraints for a recruiter that are caused by the rapid growth of a startup?**

Comment: I am thinking of "immediate availability", "being operational from day 1", "limited time to recruit/select candidates", etc. But I'm looking for experience-based answers, rather than thought of.

Comment: By far your best bet here is to *talk to the company*. Different companies will look for different things.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I have an informal chat scheduled in a few days. But my objective is to prepare beforehand, and to know what advantages I may have; or what is critical for me to highlight in my application. I.e. to **understand them, in order to better meet their expectations**.

Comment: This question is **very** broad.  VTC

Comment: @MisterPositive I knew my issue was broad, so I've focused my question as much as I could, and made it non opinion-based. So I don't share your opinion, but you'd know better if it suits this site or not.

Comment: @ebo I appreciate you've tried to make it as narrow as you can, but it's still too broad. There is no one set of "specific requirements and constraints that are caused by the rapid growth of a startup" - some companies in that phase need bodies to churn out relatively simple code and want relatively junior staff, some need to improve their team's skills and want relatively experience staff, some need staff now to deal with an immediate need, some are looking to the future and are prepared to wait, etc, etc. *It all depends on the company*.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to tell, apply and hope for the best.

If you do get the job be more careful than usual about creating a positive impression.

The reason I say this is that one thing that often happens is they will purposely overhire since they're short on time, with the idea that if they hire 5 they can maybe get rid of two or three if they need to, quite often they'll hire 5 and still advertise the positions.

Comment: *over-hiring* is an interesting point I hadn't thought through!

Comment: it's an angle worth considering in a time constrained situation.